# Paypal OAuth login returns (invalid client_ID or redirect_uri)

Tags: paypal, oauth, asp.net-core, invalid-url

I am trying to implement Paypal Oauth login in my website and keep on getting this error:

> We're sorry about that
>
> Looks like this action is not supported. Please
>   return and report this error so that we can support it in the future.
>   (invalid client_ID or redirect_uri)

This is sandbox environment and the redirect_uri I have tried with are:

1. no url
2. http://127.0.0.1:5000/signin-paypal
3. http://localhost:5000/signin-paypal

I have double, tripple check the client_id and client_secret, which match with application setup on Paypal developer desktop.

Absolutely got no clue, why it is failing.

Note: few other providers I have used (google, facebook, linkedin, github amazon) are working perfectly fine with same code.

Comment: [probably the Solution](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/issues/198)

Comment: @Nexus23 hey have you solved the problem? i have the same issue as you.

Comment: If you can answer the question, it is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66434771/invalid-return-invalid-client-id-or-redirect-uri

Comment: The saved and param values should match exactly. It also started working for me after adding an ending `/` to both.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you are using exact same Redirect URL as in app settings as well, not just client ID/secret

P.S. Sorry for necroposting