# Invalid return invalid client_id or redirect_uri

Tags: javascript, paypal, payment-gateway, payment, paypal-ipn

Currently i'm trying to connect with paypal oauth login on my web app. However I'm getting this error

[image]

The clientside code

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/connect/api.js"></script>
<script>
  paypal.use(["login"], function (login) {
    login.render({
      appid:
        "<I took from the client id>",
      scopes: "openid profile email address",
      containerid: "cwppButton",
      responseType: "code",
      locale: "en-us",
      buttonType: "CWP",
      buttonShape: "pill",
      buttonSize: "md",
      fullPage: "true",
      returnurl: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/paypal-return",
    });
  });
</script>
```

The clientID

[image]

The return URL

[image]

Is there anything that I missed here, I couldn't find the error that is pointing in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Try some returnurl on a domain with https

Comment: @PrestonPHX Thanks for suggesting, unfortunately, it doesn't work as well. I set both on the javascript and Paypal this URL `https://127.0.0.1:8080/paypal-return` but no luck.

Comment: This is what i get from the URL - `https://www.paypal.com/connect/?flowEntry=md&client_id=<ID>&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20address&redirect_uri=https%25253A%25252F%25252F127.0.0.1%253A8080%252Fpaypal-return&newUI=Y`

Comment: On a domain... i.e. not an IP address, and by https I mean the default port, no :8080

Comment: So for example using something like ngrok? and set the the domain to something like HTTP://312313.ngrok.com:443? Thanks

Comment: I would first try something like `https://www.google.com`

Answer (score 0):

With the following code it works for me. I had the same issue and included this: "authend": "sandbox"
**Full code:**

```
    <span id='lippButton'></span>
    <script src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/api.js'></script>
    <script>
        paypal.use( ['login'], function (login) {
            login.render ({
                "appid":"<MY APP ID>",
                "authend": "sandbox",
                "scopes":"openid",
                "containerid":"lippButton",
                "responseType":"code",
                "locale":"en-us",
                "buttonType":"LWP",
                "buttonShape":"pill",
                "buttonSize":"lg",
                "fullPage":"true",
                "returnurl":"http://127.0.0.1/CyFlying/public/"
            });
        });
    </script>
```